# Pentaho User Console login incorrectly redirecting to licensing page

Tags: redirect, ldap, pentaho

I am in the process of adapting the security configurations to LDAP on the Pentaho BI-server. I made the modifications a while back (simply to direct Pentaho where the LDAP references were), and the login process worked just fine. No other modifications have been made to the configuration.

However, the free month trial that I had been using ran out, and I had to switch to an Enterprise license. Ever since then, I have been having problems with the login. I am using a Firefox browser on a Linux VM.

When I enter my LDAP login credentials (that I am sure are correct and working) (Screenshot 1: Normal-appearing login screen hosted at localhost:8080/pentaho/Login)

[image: Normal Pentaho User Console login screen]

I am redirected to the page I first saw when my free trial ran out (Screenshot 2). I see the error

> Missing or expired license. To continue you must update your Pentaho BI Platform license. If you are not ready now you may log out and come back later.

but it shows all my licenses as up-to-date and valid.

[image: Falsely redirected license authentication page]

I would think that this is maybe some sort of glitch, except that if I modify the web address it redirected me to

```
http://localhost:8080/pentaho/api/repos/admin-plugin/resources/licenseManagerModule/licenseManagerAdmin.html
```

and change it to

```
http://localhost:8080/pentaho/
```

after putting in my credentials, I am taken to my User Console dashboard, and I am logged in.

I am not even sure what type of problem I am running into. Is it coding related, browser related, Pentaho server related, or something else altogether? I would appreciate some guidance into where I might look to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is indeed a missing license. You need `Pentaho BI Platform Enterprise Edition` license to run PUC.

Comment: I hadn't realized that the BI Platform was its own license, I thought it was referring to the entire system. Adding that license fixed everything. Thanks.